# How to send post to diffrent website and recive result without redirecting

Tags: php, html, post, web, load

i just trying to write a small php script that allow me to get information from website "link below"  and load to some div on my website :

```
https://www.sspcrs.ie/portal/checker/home.do
```

info : no. 324234 is valid

Comment: Use the PHP cURL functions. Or for simple cases just use `file_get_contents($url)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use curl to grab a url and include post data. Once you have the response you can echo this into your div on your page. This link demonstrates curl and post: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post