# Can I pass PHP along for 2 pages?

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that will be filled out by clients. The `<form>`'s action tag references my online database (not at my site) and then goes back to my site to continue navigation to from the "thank you" page onwards.

How can I pass the form's completed data to the "thankyou.php" back at my site after passing through the online database?

Comment: If you are submitting to another site that is not your own, then all your form data is in their control. Would it be possible to maybe do an AJAX call on submit and set it in the users session so you can display when they come back to your site? Ps. awesome avatar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing data to "thank you" page when form action goes to third party site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892669/passing-data-to-thank-you-page-when-form-action-goes-to-third-party-site)

Comment: You could save the information in `$_SESSION` variables before posting it.  It should still be there when they get redirected back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the database handler redirect to thankyou.php followed by a query string. Example: http://examplesite.com/thankyou.php?status=success&username=JimBob&email=jimbob%40example.com.

Then you can use urldecode($_GET['status']), urldecode($_GET['username']) and urldecode($_GET['email']) in your thank you script to echo the values back to the user.

Of course, you would have to program the database side to url_encode the values and knit together a string to send to thankyou.php. You'd also have I be careful that there's no sensitive data in the query string like passwords or credit card numbers.

If you don't have control of the database, you could redirect to a php script that sets session variables and then posts to the database. The problems with that approach is that it would show thank you even if there was an error in the database. Also, you now have 3 redirects which is a problem on Apple mobile devices.